# RSpec as_null_object to return nil or false

Tags: ruby, rspec, cancan

I need something similar to as_null_object, that can respond to any methods not explicitly set and returns nil or false. I cannot use as_null_object because it returns a mock object (true equivalent) when calling an undefined method.

My use case is testing the cancan's ability.rb model below:

```
if user.admin?
  # set abilities
end
#...many other if statements with respect to the different roles...
if user.publisher?
  # set abilities
end
```

In this case, user has many boolean role methods. In my test, I want to test just one role in isolation by creating a mock user object with just one role without having to stub out all the other roles. If the role methods are not defined I want it to return nil or false so it doesn't set the other abilities. Something like:

```
user = mock("User", :publisher? => true).all_other_methods_to_return(false)
```

Ref: http://apidock.com/rspec/Spec/Mocks/Methods/as_null_object

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach is not the best. I generally consider "white list" approaches better than "black list". So I would do something like the following:

```
 def mock_user_with_role(role)
   roles = %w(admin publisher) #add the rest of the roles here or do something like User::Roles
   stubbed_methods = Hash[(roles - [role]).map {|r| ["#{r}?", false]}]
   double("User", stubbed_methods.merge("#{role}?" => true))
 end
```

The above method will return a mock `User` which will return false for all other roles besides the passed role.

**To answer you question**, though, you can do what you want with something like the following:

```
 user = double(Hash[User.methods.grep(/\?$/).map{|m| [m, false]}])
 user.stub("publisher?" => true)
```

The above might be a bit "dangerous" and lead to strange results since you are redefining methods that belong to `User`'s ancestors e.g. `Kernel` and `BasicObject`. To solve this you can instead use a subset of the `User` methods by doing something like:

```
 (User.methods - RSpec::Mocks::Mock.methods)
```

As a last alternative you can do something like the following:

```
user = double("publisher?" => true)
def user.method_missing(name, *args, &block)
  false
end
```

But this is quite a hack and you might want to avoid it :)

Comment: Yea I did something very similar. I defined a high level `let(:user) {double("User", :admin?=> false, :publisher? => false, :other_role?=> false}` to default all the methods I care about to false and then within each role I'm describing, I override one of the methods to true, e.g., `user.stub(:publisher? => true)`